# How to cast ctid system column into long and vice versa

Tags: postgresql

Using PostgreSQL version 9+ how to convert hidden system column ctid into long type ?

With this long value, how to convert into tid type again ?

Comment: Out of interest ... why?

Comment: A single value is easier to manage into software application than a tuple.

Comment: It's rare for people to use `ctid` safely / correctly. It's hidden for a reason. What're you trying to do with it?

Comment: Id do like QGis, use ctid in order to identify selected rows when there is no primary key.

Comment: ... then that's one of those "wrong" usages. `ctid` can change, e.g. after a `CLUSTER` or `VACUUM FULL`. Or an `UPDATE`. It's *absolutely* wrong to use it as a key of any kind. (Even if you don't do these things, `autovacuum` can potentially.)

Comment: We are aware of this problem, but we can not prevent the user to select rows if he does not define a primary key. At best we could warn him.The lifetime of the selection is short. We think about disabling editing features on table that does not have primary keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ctid** can be decomposed into/from long without losing data using bitwise operations:

Convert a **ctid** column into a long type [(source)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/66007):

```
((ctid::text::point)[0]::bigint << 32) | (ctid::text::point)[1]::bigint as long_ctid
```

Convert a long to a **tid** type:

```
ctid = CONCAT('(', long_ctid >> 32,',',long_ctid << 32 >> 32,')')::tid
```

Comment: Pretty sure that'll fall apart if either ctid component is greater than 2^31, or the long value overflows long but not 'unsigned long', due to lack of unsigned types in Pg.

Comment: Following source, ctid components are unsigned 32 bits integers. Then two will fit into bigint.

Comment: Er, but `bigint` is unsigned. So you're trying to fit 3 * 32 bits into a 63 bit value. It'd be OK if you handled sign wrap (to use the 64th bit), but you don't seem to.

Comment: Why 3*32 bits, there is only 2 components ? Do you know how to handle sign wrap ?

Comment: Er, 2*32 bits. Sorry.